# Why doesnt put and take work here?

Tags: java, concurrent-programming, java.util.concurrent

```
class NaiveSQ<E> {
    boolean putting = false;
    E item = null;

    public synchronized E take() throws InterruptedException {
        while (item == null)
            wait();
        E e = item;
        item = null;
        notifyAll();
        return e;
    }

    public synchronized void put (E e) throws InterruptedException {
        if (e == null)
            return;
        while (putting)
            wait();
        putting = true;
        item = e;
        notifyAll();
        while (item != null)
            wait();
        putting = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    int id = -1;
    int limit = 1;

    Producer(int x) {
        id = x;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("I am producer number %d\n", id);
        for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
            Integer I = new Integer(i);
            try {
                Test.queue.put(I);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    int id = -1;

    Consumer(int x) {
        id = x;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Integer I = Test.queue.take();
            System.out.printf(
                "I am consumer number %d - I read %d\n", id, I.intValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class Test{
    static NaiveSQ<Integer> queue;
    public static void main (String [] args){
        System.out.println("hello from Java");
        Thread p = new Thread(new Producer(1));
        p.start();
        for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
            Thread c = new Thread(new Consumer(i));
            c.start();
        }
    }
};
```

Also why does the exception contain null?
This is an implementation from http://www.cs.rice.edu/~wns1/papers/2006-PPoPP-SQ.pdf listing 3

I get output as

```
hello from Java
I am producer number 1
null
null
```

why do I get null?

Comment: What specific error are you getting here?  What do you mean by "why doesn't the exception contain null?"

Answer (score 4):

You haven't initated the queue in your main method. I guess you get a NullPointerException since the queue object is never created and the Producer and Consumer refers to the queue which is null.

Comment: how should I do that, sorry but I have no experience with java

Comment: That is among the first thing to learn. I advise you to read a book on the basics of Java. static NaiveSQ<Integer> queue = new NaiveSQ<Integer>();

Answer (score 0):

Even if you initialize the queue properly, still your implementation has a major issue. If the `Consumer` thread tries to *take* an item when the queue is empty (which is totally possible according to your code), then `Consumer` thread enters into an indefinite wait holding the lock to the object. `Producer` thread can never *put* an item to the queue. The whole thing will halt.